# Proving Exponential Equations are Equivalent 2

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

Prove that the following equations are equivalent,

$2^{2^{x-1}}=\frac{1}{2^{2^{x}}-1}$ and $2^{2^{x+1}}=\frac{1}{2^{2^{x-1}}-1}$

They both have an approximate solution of -.30157 when put in a calculator, but I'm completely how to show they are equal through changing their forms or using log properties. Any hints or suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Denote $z = 2^{2^{x-1}}$, then we have to show equivalence of the equations 
$$
z = \frac{1}{z^2 - 1}, \tag1 
$$
$$
z^4 = \frac{1}{z - 1}, \tag2
$$
or after simple rearranging 
$$
z^3 - z - 1 = 0, \tag1
$$
$$
z^5 - z^4 - 1 = 0. \tag2
$$
More precisely, we want to see that these equations have the same real roots (because we assume $z = 2^{2^{x-1}}$ is real for real $x$). One may see that 
$$
z^5 - z^4 - 1 = (z^3 - z - 1)(z^2 - z + 1),
$$
and since polynomial $z^2 - z + 1$ has no real roots, we conclude that $(1)$ has the same real roots as $(2)$.